# Time complexity of the code below

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o

I am trying to check the time complexity of the below simple program.
The program replaces spaces in a string with `'%20'`.

1. The loop to count spaces (O(1) time)

   ```
       foreach (char k in s)
       {
           if (k == ' ')
           {
               spaces_cnt++;
           }
       }
   ```
2. The loop to replace the spaces (O(n) where n is size of string)

   ```
       char[] c = new char[s.Length + spaces_cnt * 3];
       int i = 0;
       int j = 0;
       while (i<s.Length)
       {
           if (s[i] != ' ')
           {
               c[j] = s[i];
               j++;
               i++;
           }
           else
           {

               c[j] = '%';
               c[j + 1] = '2';
               c[j + 2] = '0';
               j = j + 3;
               i++;
           }
       }
   ```

So I am guessing it is a "O(n) + O(1)" solution. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: FYI O(n) + O(1) is O(n).

Comment: The first loop is of course O(n) as well, and O(n)+O(n)=O(n).

Comment: @Joe I guess you meant O(n) + O(n) but it would be still O(n) and not O(2n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loop to count spaces takes `O(n)`, not `O(1)`, since you’re iterating over – and performing a check on – each of the `n` characters in your string.

As you stated, the replacement loop takes `O(n)`. Two `O(n)` operations performed sequentially have a combined complexity of `O(n)` (constant factors are discarded in Big-O notation).

P.S. You know that you can achieve the equivalent of all your code using a single line?

```
s = s.Replace(" ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to encode a string.  If that's the case, you can use the [UrlPathEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlpathencode.aspx)() method.  If you're only trying to encode spaces, use Replace() (as mentioned by Douglas).